# How to perform an aggregation only query in Phonograph with the API

Tags: python, python-requests, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api, foundry-phonograph

I want to run a phonograph aggregation query from the API and don't manage to set the `pageSize`.
When I run an aggregation query from Slate, I can set the `pageSize` Parameter to `0` which has the effect, that I get only the aggregation in the result.

Here the complete preview from Slate of my query:

```
{
    "extractors": {
        "result": "$"
    },
    "headers": {},
    "method": "POST",
    "path": "search/tables",
    "pathParams": {},
    "queryParams": {
        "pageSize": 0
    },
    "bodyJson": {
        "tableRids": [
            "ri.phonograph2.main.table.xxxx"
        ],
        "filter": {
            "type": "and",
            "and": []
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "distincCrit": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "type.raw",
                    "order": {
                        "_term": "asc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to perform this as well from the command-line in python. So I set up my code. The json-parameter is filled with the `bodyJson` from above.

```
response = requests.post(PHONOAPI_SEARCH_API, headers=HEADERS, json=searchAgg, verify=False, proxies=proxies).text
```

But I find no way to add the `queryParams` with the `pageSize` to my python Code.

Any suggestion?

I tried to add the `pageSize` Attribute to the json and the header without effect. I tried as well to pass the `queryParams` in the "data" parameter of the request but failed as well.

Comment: Did you try the params keyword argument?
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Thanks @nicornk ! That was the trick. Please post this as the answer. Then I'll can give my credits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the pageSize using requests [params](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) keyword arguments:

```
response = requests.post(PHONOAPI_SEARCH_API, 
                         headers=HEADERS, 
                         json=searchAgg, 
                         params={"pageSize": 100}
                         )
```